# Running laptop at full power w/heatsink but w/o fan

Tags: laptop, overheating, rendering, 3d, cpu-cooler

Background: I'm running an i5 2410m processor with tdp of 35W in an environment that occasionally reaches 38 degrees . The CPU heatsink is installed however the fan controller is dead and thus does not turn on.

Q: If I use the CPU say during 3d rendering, will thermal throttling protect the CPU or is that a condition ripe for thermal runaway and the motherboard calling an emergency shutdown?

Thanks.

Comment: An operational fan is necessary for *forced* convection to properly cool the CPU.  *Natural* convection (i.e. the heatsink alone without a fan) is insufficient to dissipate the the heat generated by the CPU.  Even with case fans, the typical PC enclosure has poor air circulation, so a CPU fan is required.

Answer (score 0):

Well, usually in a computer case there is more than one fan. Depending on the number of extra fans (one being in PSU almost always), their location and throughput it is possible.
Sawdust correctly points out that there is insufficient natural convection inside a case, but this is just part of the truth. Usually cases are designed so that forced convection moves along predetermined "routes" inside. In other words: usually CPU fan, by sucking in quite a lot of air, is cooling everything else inside a computer (i.e. HDDs, RAM, chipset), with CPU being the last - but with biggest sink and fast fan not in the least the least. Same with case fan, but this is usually less effective than CPU fan (obviously, as it is spinning much slower.

SO the bottom line is: it depends. Can be done, but in most conditions not possible, leading to emergency shut down.

Comment: Well I performed Intel burn test for 30 iterations or 2253 seconds and the CPU temperature pretty much stays pegged at 95 degrees centigrade. It does however modulate the voltage to keep power output beneath tdp and throttles the CPU from 2.3GHz to 1.2GHz. It seems to me that the architecture regulates itself pretty well without forced convection through the heatsink. I never saw it exceed 95 degrees and I never saw it throttle more than 1.2GHz. Ambient temperature is 22 degrees

Comment: 95C is about right for stressed Intel CPU. They can go hotter than that, but it's not recommended and it showed in your tests. And you have severe performance penalty. Anyway, like in the saying I'm quite fond of: the fact that you can do something doesn't mean you should do it... Temp events have cumulative effect on all kinds of IC devices. So the longer and hotter your rig works, the shorter it will work overall.

Answer (score 0):

I had a i7-4790 CPU that was running hot all the time.  The built-in thermal throttling did not seem to work well.  The computer would blank the screen and hang when the CPU got too hot.  On that basis I wouldn't trust the thermal throttling to keep the PC running.  If it's not critical, you could try it out and see what happens, I had no apparent lasting damage to the chip YMMV.